# Balls into bins: explanation for $n=2$

Tags: probability

I discovered that the maximum number of balls in any bin in *a random allocation of $n$ balls into  $n$ bins* is equal to $$\dfrac{\log n}{\log\log n},$$ with probability $1-1/n$. How to interpret this for fixed $n$? For example, for $n=2$, what does it mean to have $$\dfrac{\log 2}{\log\log 2}=-1.89\ldots$$

Comment: It means the formula is an asymptotic formula which is not very good for very small values of $n$.

Comment: For most $n$, the expression will not even be an integer, hence the maximum number will *never* be equal to it.

Comment: That quotient *can't* be an integer (if $n$ is).

Comment: Any thoughts, zbir?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I think Lord Shark is right. At first I thought that the maximum load for $n=2$ would be something >0 with probability $1/2$. But as said in the comments, I understand that I should not fix $n$.